# Am I still eligible for an evisitor Visa for Australia if I have two nationalities?

Tags: visas, australia, dual-nationality

I have asked a visa (evisitor) to the Australian government and I have declared that I have to nationalities (a Russian one and a Belgian one). Am I still eligible for an evisitor visa or should I apply to a different kind of visa ?

Thanks for your help I cannot seem to reach the border department of Australia and on their websites there is nothing described concerning this query.

Answer (score 2):

When you have two passports you usually only present one to the country you're visiting. It's doubtful Australia cares about your other nationalities as long as the passport you present adheres to the rules about it.

Australia lets you apply for an [evisitor visa online](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/651-/eVisitor-Online-application) ([subclass 651](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/651-?tab=1&heading=who-could-get-this-visa)) if you hold a passport from Belgium, and for a visitor visa (also [online](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-), [subclass 600](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-/Visitor-e600-visa-online-applications)) if you decide to travel with your Russian passport. Those are both different, you should apply for one *or* the other and once you decide which passport to go with, you should stick with that decision.

Also note that an ETA is *not* a visa and neither of your passports qualifies you for one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have indeed applied for a eVisitor (subclass 651). In the form there is a question concerning other citizenship that I hold and this is why I was wondering if having a Russian citizenship ment that I had to apply for an other type of visa. What do you mean with neither of my passport are applicable for an ETA? How is this linked with the eVisitor visa?